# Create weighted mean per column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe and I want to create weighted columns based on the number of times values appear, per label in column `label`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['a',1,1,1],
    ['a',1,23,10],
    ['a',1,2,2], 
    ['b',1,14,2], 
    ['a',255,255,255]
]
,columns=['w','r','g','b']
)
```

In column `label` there are 4 instances of **a** and one of **b**. For label **a** in column `r` there are three 1's (75%) and one 255 (25%) and for letter **b** there is one 1 (100%). How can I multiply the original matrix so that each value is weighted by the number of times it appears in the column, grouped by column `label`, using pandas?

As an example, column `r` would become:

```
[a    1   * 0.75 \\percentages
 a    1   * 0.75
 a    1   * 0.75
 b    1   * 1.0
 a    255 * 0.25]
```

I want to do this for each of the columns `r`, `g` and `b`.

I've managed to factor my numbers down based on the number of times they appear per label but I'm not sure how to apply this back to the original dataframe:

```
weighted = pd.DataFrame()
cols = [x for x in pw.columns if x != 'w']
for col in cols:
    other_col = [x for x in cols if x != col and x!='w'][0]
    
    g = df.groupby(by=['w', col]).agg('count')
    w = pd.DataFrame(g.index.get_level_values(1) * (g[other_col] / g[other_col].groupby('w').sum()[g[other_col].index.get_level_values(0)].values))
    weighted = pd.concat([weighted, w], axis=0)
weighted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) + [value_counts](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
percentage = df.groupby('w').transform(lambda x: x.map(x.value_counts(normalize=True)))
print(percentage)
```

**Output**

```
      r     g     b
0  0.75  0.25  0.25
1  0.75  0.25  0.25
2  0.75  0.25  0.25
3  1.00  1.00  1.00
4  0.25  0.25  0.25
```

If you want to overwrite the original DataFrame, do:

```
df.iloc[:, 1:] = df.groupby('w').transform(lambda x: x.map(x.value_counts(normalize=True)))
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   w     r     g     b
0  a  0.75  0.25  0.25
1  a  0.75  0.25  0.25
2  a  0.75  0.25  0.25
3  b  1.00  1.00  1.00
4  a  0.25  0.25  0.25
```

Comment: Amazing, I knew there would be much slimmer way to do this!